# Как в данном случае применить Dependency Injection контейнер?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Как в данном случае применить Dependency Injection контейнер?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddScoped<IEmployee, Worker>();
            services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var qwe = new Some();
        }
    }
    public class Some
    {
        private IEmployee _employee;
        public Some(IEmployee employee)
        {
            _employee = employee;
        }
        public void DoIt()
        {
            _employee.DoWork();
        }
    }
    public interface IEmployee
    {
        void DoWork();
    }
    internal class Manager : IEmployee
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do some more important...");
        }
    }
    public class Worker : IEmployee
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do something");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Мат убирайте из кода, что за дет. сад то...? А так, если вы используете контейнер, то забудьте про `new`, регистрируйте все в нем, и через него и спрашивайте нужные объекты, в которые он сам встроит все типы (если те есть в контейнере).

Comment: Можно пример кода, каким образом вызывать из контейнера?
P.S Это не мат, это название класса

Comment: провайдер билдите, но его не используете, var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();, а дальше используйте провайдер для получения сервиса и вызывайте его методы

Comment: Вы будете еще отрицать, что это мат? Серьезно? Да без разницы где это, хоть в комментариях, хоть в названии переменных, хоть где. Это мат, которому не место на этом ресурсе. Код, вам часть сказали выше, дальше просто `var result = provider.GetService<Тип>();`.

Comment: [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) - начните отсюда.

Comment: [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) - и вот ещё.

Comment: Не учите человека плохому! `ServiceProvider` - это анти-паттерн Service Locator.

Comment: Не согласен. Если человек только начинает вникать в это, он должен понимать как все устроено, а что более понятней, простой вызов метода, или создание хоста, его регистрации, и так далее? Да и хосты на сколько я знаю есть не у всех контейнеров (могу ошибаться), вот научим человека хостами пользоваться, а он не будет знать основ, захочет поставить другой контейнер, и опять прибежит сюда спрашивать "что не так?". Для понимания паттернов и анти-паттернов, нужно понимание основы, которой у автора вопроса пока нет.